# How to query on something other than id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with these fields:

```
Department:
name:string
deptid:integer
```

I've run `rake db:migrate` and have seeded the table with 5 records.  In the departments controller, I have:

```
def show
  @dept = Department.find(params[:deptid])
end
```

In show.html.erb:

```
<%= @dept.name %>
```

In routes.rb

```
get 'departments/:deptid' => 'departments#show'
```

When I do this localhost:3000/show/2, I get the second record.  If I instead use localhost:3000/show/212, where deptid=212 is valid, I get a

> Couldn't find Department with 'id' = 212

error.  Since I have specified deptid and not id (primary key), why does it still look for the PK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` method will always look up a record by its primary key - in this case, you have not changed the primary key, so it is trying to look up records by `id`.

If you want to look up a single record by a different field, you can use `find_by` (or `find_by!`, the difference being that `find_by!` will raise an exception if no record is found, just like `find` does). In this case, you probably want:

```
Department.find_by!(deptid: params[:deptid])
```